# How can i pull a specific folder from origin (Remote repository) into my local master repository

Tags: git

unfortunately i deleted a src folder from my local master branch. Now i would like to pull or clone JUST the src file again from the origin. Is it possible to do that?
When yes, how can i solve this issue...

Any suggestion is welcome...

Thanks in advance

Comment: When under version control deletes can be easily undone. That's one of the benefits.

Comment: And with git you don't even need the origin for that. You can do it locally.

Comment: Hey Martinho, 
many thanks for your quick response. I am using the git-bash for win-xp. would you please tell me, which command to use? i tried the command: git ls -files -d to show deleted files. but without success..

Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
git checkout src
```

Comment: Or `git checkout master -- src/` (or just `git checkout .` to restore everything in current (sub)directory)

Comment: Hey Thanks, 
Your recommendation doesn't work. Since the src folder in the master branch does not exist longer. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ja, do you mean to say that you deleted the directory (probably using *git rm*) and then committed it? In that case, the simplest solution is to find the particular commit (using *git log*) and then do *git revert <commit-id>*.